# AWSLexVoiceButton prompting and client fulfillment response

Tags: ios, aws-sdk, amazon-lex

I am using the AWS SDK to add a AWSLexVoiceButton to my app.   I have it configured for client fulfillment in the Intent I set up, as I want to make the app show something on the screen based on voice command in the AWS Console for my Intent:

[image: AWS fulfillment]

This all works, and I get a callback in the code below when the Bot recognizes my Intent:

```
func voiceButton(_ button: AWSLexVoiceButton, on response: AWSLexVoiceButtonResponse) {
    // `inputranscript` is the transcript of the voice input to the operation
    if response.dialogState == .readyForFulfillment {
        print("Ready to fulfill")
        // I want to provide speech output
        say(text: "OK, I will show the train status screen")
        showTrainStatusScreen()
    }
}
```

Two problems:

1. When I tap the AWSLexVoiceButton, there is no audio indication that it is listening, and you see no indication you even tapped on the button unless you make a loud enough sound to cause its microphone sound detection animation.  I can find no way to add a voice prompt like "How can I help you?" because there are no `AWSLexVoiceButtonDelegate` callbacks when the button is initially tapped.

   **Q: Is there any way to add an audio prompt when Lex beings listening?**
2. Similarly, there is no audio indication that the client is fulfilling the intent.   Because there is a callback, I can add my own response.  But to do so, I manually set up a `AVAudioPlayer` and integrate with AWS Polly to convert my text to speech in a custom `say` method I wrote.  My approach works, but it seems like it must be the wrong way.

   **Q: Is there any way to trigger Lex to give a custom audio response as a result of client fulfillment?**

Comment: Is the fulfillment image relevant here? I assume your fulfillment is a lambda function, based on the question content.

Comment: It's actually not a lambda function.  For my use case, I simply need to launch a screen on voice command, so no server-side computations are required.

Comment: In that case, I've updated my answer for question 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **You cannot provide a response via Lex without a request from the user.** I'm not familiar with iOS, however in Android you can add this functionality within your application to handle this situation manually. I would guess iOS allows similar functionality. Please comment if I am wrong. Unfortunately, this is not something that Lex provides.
2. **Lex will only respond once the fulfillment is *complete*.** Since you do not require server side fulfillment, you can create a lambda function which does nothing except return the completion response you are looking for.

Hope that helps

Comment: Adding a lambda to give a custom voice response is surprisingly easy. 
 You can use the Amazon sample [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs2-prepare.html), changing only the text response. 
 This still will send all the info about what triggered in the same callback to `func voiceButton(_ button: AWSLexVoiceButton, on response: AWSLexVoiceButtonResponse)` but with  `response.dialogState == .fulfilled` instead of `response.dialogState == .readyForFulfillment `, so my custom fulfillment logic can stay there.